modify timestamp with exiftool with milliseconds
I have an image that shows this info with exiftool
exiftool frame_0003.png
ExifTool Version Number         : 11.88
File Name                       : frame_0003.png
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 18 MB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2024:06:02 13:08:17+02:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2024:06:02 13:08:13+02:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2024:06:02 13:08:17+02:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : PNG
File Type Extension             : png
MIME Type                       : image/png
Image Width                     : 3840
Image Height                    : 2160
Bit Depth                       : 8
Color Type                      : RGB
Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
Filter                          : Adaptive
Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
Pixels Per Unit X               : 0
Pixels Per Unit Y               : 1
Pixel Units                     : Unknown
White Point X                   : 0.3127
White Point Y                   : 0.329
Red X                           : 0.64
Red Y                           : 0.33
Green X                         : 0.3
Green Y                         : 0.6
Blue X                          : 0.15
Blue Y                          : 0.06
Gamma                           : 1.961
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exif Version                    : 0232
Date/Time Original              : 2024:04:26 14:24:50
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Flashpix Version                : 0100

I tried to modidied the Date/Time to add milliseconds using
exiftool -d "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S.%3f" -overwrite_original -DateTimeOriginal="2024:04:26 14:24:50.100" frame_0003.png

while the commands does not give any errors, this does not modify the time stamps in the metadata.

Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about using exiftool, not about programming, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  See Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on? for guidance.

First, a correction.  The -d (-dateFormat) option is not needed in this command, as you are already using the default format exiftool uses for writing date/time tags.  Additionally, exiftool is very flexible about writing date/time values. As long as there are 14 numbers to cover the Year to Second values, it will be able to parse the values.  See Exiftool FAQ #5,"How do I format date and time information for writing?"
There are three main date/time values in the EXIF spec.  Each of these are split into three separate tags.
The main ones that hold the Year:Month:Day Hour:Minute:Second are the DateTimeDigitized (called CreateDate by exiftool), DateTimeOriginal, and DateTime (called ModifyDate by exiftool). DateTimeOriginal holds the time stamp when the image was created. DateTimeDigitized holds the time stamp when the image was turned into a digital file.  For digital cameras, these two time stamps will be the same, but they technically should be different if the image was taken with an analog camera (DateTimeOriginal) and then later scanned into a digital file (DateTimeDigitized). The DateTime is the last time the image itself has been altered, such as color correction or editing in Photoshop.
The time zones for each of these are held in a separate tag, OffsetTimeDigitized, OffsetTimeOriginal, and OffsetTime respectively.
And to finally answer your question, the subseconds for each of these is held in yet another tag SubSecTimeDigitized, SubSecTimeOriginal, and SubSecTime.  So in order to set the milliseconds, you need to set these subsecond tags.
Luckily, exiftool provides a shortcut tag for this mess that will set all three tags for each of these groups at once. These shortcuts are as follows, with the exiftool name for the tag in parentheses

SubSecCreateDate: Sets DateTimeDigitized (CreateDate), OffsetTimeDigitized, and SubSecTimeDigitized
SubSecDateTimeOriginal: Sets DateTimeOriginal, OffsetTimeOriginal, and SubSecTimeOriginal
SubSecModifyDate: Sets DateTime (ModifyDate), OffsetTime, and SubSecTime

An updated version of your command would be
exiftool -overwrite_original -SubSecDateTimeOriginal="2024:04:26 14:24:50.100" frame_0003.png

Final note, there are XMP versions for each of these time stamps (XMP:CreateDate, XMP:DateTimeOriginal, and XMP:ModifyDate) but since XMP data is much more flexible, these tags include subseconds and time zones. The same command used to instead write the XMP data would be
exiftool -overwrite_original -XMP:DateTimeOriginal="2024:04:26 14:24:50.100" frame_0003.png


The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.
